# verificar caracteres não permitidos dentro do input e alertar usuário

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia.
Num sistema em que eu estou trabalhando, existe esse input dentro da primeira div, e eu preciso verificar quando o usuário digitar as letras **I**, **O**, **Q** em qualquer um dos 17 caracteres do input, apareça um texto na div "resCh" informando que ele digitou uma dessas letras, e não deixe ele continuar escrevendo até ele apagar estes caracteres.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
   <input id="txtCh" name="Ch" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onCut="return false" maxlength="17"/>
</div>
<div id="resCh" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="color:red"></div>
```

A validação é para ser feita em JS, estou iniciando em JS, ainda, e tentei fazer essa função, mas não me atendeu:

```
function isValidChar() {
    const alert = "INPUT CONTÉM LETRAS PROIBIDAS (I, O, Q)";

    const res = document.querySelector("#resCh");
    let written = document.querySelector("#txtCh").value;
    if (
        written.indexOf("o") != -1 ||
        written.indexOf("i") != -1 ||
        written.indexOf("q") != -1 ||
        written.indexOf("O") != -1 ||
        written.indexOf("I") != -1 ||
        written.indexOf("Q") != -1
    ) {
        document.getElementById("resCh").innerHTML = alert;
        document.getElementById("resCh").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("resCh").style.display = "none";
    }

   }
```

**um edit: **
Preciso monitorar o clique também, para validar essa mensagem... tentei fazer um:

```
document.documentElement.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target !== res) {
        res.style.display = "block";
      }
      else{
        res.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

mas acabei bugando a mensagem, não sei o que está errado.

Grato desde já

Comment: Uma coisa que pode te ajudar na verificação é usar uma expressão regular. No seu `if` você pode usar `if (/[iIoOqQ]/.test(written)) { `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para checar os caracteres inválidos você pode usar o `.test()` com a expressão regular abaixo:

```
/[oiq]/i.test(written)
```

O conjunto `[oiq]` verifica se na string existe as letras `o`, `i` ou `q`, e a flag `i` ignora se for maiúsculo ou minúsculo.

No input você usará 3 eventos, chamando a mesma função: `onpaste`, `onkeypress` e `oninput`:

```
<input id="txtCh" name="Ch" onpaste="isValidChar(event)" onkeypress="isValidChar(event)" oninput="isValidChar()" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onCut="return false" maxlength="17"/>
```

Como os eventos `onpaste` e `onkeypress` são canceláveis você irá enviar para a função o evento com `event` como parâmetro, e na função irá recebe-lo como argumento:

```
function isValidChar(e) {
                     ↑
```

Se algum dos caracteres inválidos for inserido no input, você irá cancelar o evento `onkeypress` ou `onpaste` com `preventDefault()`, fazendo com que nada possa ser inserido no campo até que o caractere inválido seja apagado.

O evento `onpaste` é disparado quando o usuário tentar colar um texto no campo.

Veja funcionando:

```js
function isValidChar(e) {

    const alert = "INPUT CONTÉM LETRAS PROIBIDAS (I, O, Q)";

    const res = document.querySelector("#resCh");
    let written = document.querySelector("#txtCh").value;
    if (/[oiq]/i.test(written)) {
        document.getElementById("resCh").innerHTML = alert;
        document.getElementById("resCh").style.display = "block";
        if(e) e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("resCh").style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
   <input id="txtCh" name="Ch" onpaste="isValidChar(event)" onkeypress="isValidChar(event)" oninput="isValidChar()" style="text-transform: uppercase;" onCut="return false" maxlength="17"/>
</div>
<div id="resCh" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="color:red"></div>
```